# Getting Clipboard text using .net 6 and c#

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, .net-6.0

In a new VS 2022 solution, targeting .net 6, I have not been able to access the text in the clipboard.

The solution is an update of an earlier solution built in VS 2017 using .net framework 4.62.

In the past I was able to use the Clipboard Class of the System.Windows.Forms package, and retrieve the text with the following line:

```
   string textFromClipBoard = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
```

That line is not working in the new project.  The Microsoft documentation states that System.Windows.Forms is not available in .net 6 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0), and they do not provide any guidance or alternative.

FYI, my csprog file has the following PropertyGroup:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>MyTests</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Finally - I have confirmed that the text I am looking for is in the Clipboard - I opened Notepad, and did a paste, and the text was all there.

Appreciate any help...

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/app-development/clipboard-class-in-net-6/m-p/3034107

Comment: Thanks for the reference - that post was actually from me (I am krb-la in that community), from my old project mentioned above.  Please note from the csproj info I posted above that I already followed my own solution - and it did not work in the new project.  I am appreciative of your quick reply to my post, and a bit amused, but still at a loss...

Comment: Works just fine when I try it, as expected.  What does "not working" mean?  The project file looks a bit out of whack, the elements are not in the order you'd get them from the winforms project template.  Which makes it somewhat likely that the entrypoint is not declared correctly, the [STAThread] attribute on Main() is required to make the clipboard work.

Comment: I also tried and it works fine, without any problem. Check the entry point as mentioned above, or if you are using the code in a thread, set the apartment state as STA: *The Clipboard class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your Main method is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute.*

Comment: The Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text method returns an empty string.

Comment: The post linked in the first comment shows a Console app that includes Windows Forms references, hence not a WinForms Project. As mentioned in other comments here, a standard Console app doesn't decorate the `Main` entry point with `[STAThread]`, while a Project build using the standard WinForms Templates does. Check that before anything else.

Comment: I started with the Test project template.  It looks like I will need to start again with a windowsforms template.  I was hoping to avoid that - because I will am likely to have opposite issues with using the test framework namespaces

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, this project began as a Unit Test project - and does not have a Main() method.  The answers that required a decoration of the Main entry point don't apply.

I solved this with 2 methods.  One returns the Clipboard text, but runs inside the other, which runs it inside a Single Thread.

Here are the two methods I used (thanks largely to other posts here):

```
   internal static string GetTextFromClipboard()
    {
        string clipText = "";

        RunAsSTAThread(
       () =>
       {
           clipText = Clipboard.GetText();
       });

        return clipText;
    }

    internal static void RunAsSTAThread(Action goForIt)
    {
        AutoResetEvent @event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Thread thread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                goForIt();
                @event.Set();
            });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        @event.WaitOne();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this the other day using the AutoItX library, I was already using it for something else and it also happened to have a function to get the clipboard contents

```
string clipboard_contents;

clipboard_contents = AutoItX.ClipGet()
```

You can get the AutoItX libary from the nuget package manager